Supporting information from Programming Principles and Practice 3ed instructions unclear
In Stroustrup's PPP book, it says I should add #include "PPP.h" at the beginning of my programs.
So I go to the book's website 
Where he lists

How to use modules? including an explanation of how to build module PPP using PPP_support.h.
module PPP for when you can use modules.
header "PPP.h" for the easiest use of modules std and PPP.
header "PPPheaders.h" for when you have to fall back to using header files.

I don't see an actual explanation on how to implement this.
And these are the errors I get from the Error List after attempting to put this together myself:

On the "How to use modules?" link, it only briefly mentions how to enable the use of modules. Which I've already done:
Microsoft C++
When using Visual Studio.

Module files are suffixed .ixx
Set the propeties of your project. Tab: Project -> Hello project.

General properties: Set "C++ language standard" to "latest"
C/C++ general: Scan for additional module dependencies: "yes"



I already made a test to check if I could use modules and it ran succesfully, using the following on another project:
// main.cpp
import test_module;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int result = add(5, 3);
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

and
// test_module.ixx
export module test_module; // use this syntax

export int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}


The program I'm trying to build from the book and that is not working is structured as follows:
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp
#include "PPP.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "This is simplified compared to the actual program\n";
}

// PPP.h
import PPP;
using namespace PPP;
using namespace std;

// disgusting macro hack to guarantee range checking for []:
#define vector Checked_vector
#define string Checked_string
#define span Checked_span

// PPP.ixx
export module PPP;

export import std;

#define PPP_EXPORT export
#include "PPP_support.h"
using namespace PPP;

then I also have
// PPP_support.h
[...]

Which code I got from the referenced link PPP_support.h
My project settings look like this:

and this:


And these are the errors I get from the Error List:

And from the Output window:
Build started at 7:27 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Scanning sources for module dependencies...
1>Compiling...
1>PPP.ixx
1>C:\dev\ppp3\ConsoleApplication1\PPP_support.h(86,25): error C2182: 'simple_error': this use of 'void' is not valid
1>(compiling source file 'PPP.ixx')
1>C:\dev\ppp3\ConsoleApplication1\PPP_support.h(86,38): error C2065: 'string': undeclared identifier
1>(compiling source file 'PPP.ixx')
1>C:\dev\ppp3\ConsoleApplication1\PPP_support.h(86,45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 's'
1>(compiling source file 'PPP.ixx')
1>C:\dev\ppp3\ConsoleApplication1\PPP_support.h(87,2): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>(compiling source file 'PPP.ixx')
1>C:\dev\ppp3\ConsoleApplication1\PPP_support.h(87,2): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>(compiling source file 'PPP.ixx')
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 7:27 PM and took 00.407 seconds ==========

I've also tried not using modules (although I think it should work because my small program testing module stest did work) and use "header "PPPheaders.h" for when you have to fall back to using header files". But I had no success trying that either, because I think the
#define PPP_EXPORT 
#include "PPP_support.h" 

takes me back to the starting point.
I really hope someone can help me out. I just bought the book this week with great excitement and I'm looking forward to learn C++.
I also read some other forums with questions on this same issue but haven't been able to find a concrete answer. The only solution I see for now is to not use this "support" module/header, and just import std; or #include <iostream>. But it does say the use of this is recommended for execises from deeper in the book.
Big thanks!

Side note never use using namespace; in header files!

std is missing:
//PPP_support.h
PPP_EXPORT inline void simple_error(std::string s)  // write ``error: s'' and exit program (for non-exception terminating error handling)
{
    std::cerr << "error: " << s << '\n';
    exit(1);
}

check the difference:


He has using namespace std;

@3CxEZiVlQ Where is using namespace std; in PPP_support  file?

You can use the "Search on this page" in your browser.

@3CxEZiVlQ I did not find it. screenshot
